# Jewish texts in Chinese?

Tags: translation

For those familiar, I am curious to what extant holy Jewish texts have been translated into Chinese. Of course, the Bible is translated but that understand by on its own. Now, obviously, the extant of the Jewish diaspora has not really extended into Chinese speaking countries or areas. (Except for that small window ever there:) I’d be curious if there was, for example, a translation of the Talmud ever attempted. I don’t know who the people who have to be with such a particlar set of skills.

Comment: "... Jewish diaspora has not really extended into Chinese speaking countries or areas." - Not true. Google "Jews in Kaifeng" or "Jewish diaspora in China".

Comment: search web using e.g. 中国犹太人, e.g. see https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E7%8A%B9%E5%A4%AA%E4%BA%BA/79715   今天许多中国犹太人的后裔还生活在汉族和回族社群中。
no information about Chinese edition of 犹太法典［塔木德］

Comment: Chinese translations of Quran 古兰经 (except for earlier translation of some verses) only date from 1927 see https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E5%8F%A4%E8%98%AD%E7%B6%93%E8%AD%AF%E6%9C%AC%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8#600%E5%B9%B4%E4%BB%A3

Comment: The Quran is not Jewish.

Comment: mentioned because of similarities between Jewish and Muslim Chinese, 回族 in particular as far as origins are concerned, note also that OP mentioned Bible translation

Comment: search web with 塔木德 to find commercially available Chinese editions, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=%E5%A1%94%E6%9C%A8%E5%BE%B7&tag=mh0b-20&index=aps&hvadid=78615132482004&hvqmt=e&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_2himl2k54r_e 

in fact it  can be read free of charge, try: 塔木德 + 免费+在线上阅读 get http://read.jd.com/8556/418486.html

Comment: OP mentioning Bible translation is relevant because the Old Testament of the Bible IS Jewish scriptures.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. For example, see [this](https://book.douban.com/subject/2999785/). Although, according the comments, it seems it's only a small part of the Talmud.